Do I have room to add a 240V breaker in my panel?
I’m trying to see if I have room to add a 240V line for a mini split. The mini split I got is a Gree with nominal 9 amp pull and manufacturer recommended breaker size of 20 amps.
Any thoughts on an approach?
Could I use a Siemens Q22020CT2 where the pool heater or filter is to add the extra power?
Current load info:
With oven, pool pump, 2 refrigerators, 4 window AC, 1 mini split, dryer I’m about at 85A of the 200A power draw.



There are unused spaces in the panel so it's not clear why you are asking "Do I have room?"  If there's a reason you want to use a quad breaker, and if there are reasons you doubt it, you should talk about that in the question.

that empty space is where the crossover bar shown in the diagram is. I can’t install breakers there. If you count the number of breakers you’ll see there is 30 spots occupied

The usual solution I've seen is to replace four  breakers with double breakers to free up space, then plug a 240V breaker into the two spaces that you've opened up.  This may require some shuffling of circuits to put things on the right phases for load balancing. Obviously, you should check that your panel and supply will be happy with the additional load. I just gave up, upgraded to 200A supply, and as part of that had them put in a new larger box (and an entirely new set of breakers) with plenty of room for future needs. Nothing exceeds like excess...

First, the empty space.  This has to be resolved before trying to close an electrical permit.  Per the label of your G3040MB1200, "All openings must be filled with breakers or filler plates."

Next, for planning purposes, notice that you have mostly 20-amp breakers on the left, and mostly 15-amp breakers on the right.  So pick your favorite side, and then buy two of the duplex breakers to replace four of the full size breakers.  For example, on the left side, you might want 2 of Q2020U or Q2020AFC.  This frees up space for either a full size 2-pole breaker, or 2 more duplex breakers, or a whole quad package.  If you go with this strategy, some other breakers will need to be moved up because the duplex breakers are only allowed in the bottom 5 slots on each side.
Q22020CT2 is a double common trip package and doesn't make sense for replacing 2 separate breakers.  I'm guessing you didn't realize it was different from the Q22020CTU breaker.  The latter has a single common trip that would work for the 20-amp mini split.  Alternatively, you could use the CT2 version to replace the 2-pole breaker in slots 25 and 27.

Thanks for this feedback, it was exactly what I was looking. Cheers

In a panel that large that has been around for a while, you may find breakers that are unused or underused, and that can be combined to free spaces.  As an example, "back porch ceiling", if it serves only one 3W LED bulb, does not need its own breaker.  It may of course serve other things, but you get the idea.  Some are unlabeled.  If you can find two pairs of breakers suitable for combining, you'll free up two spaces.
